# How to set BarChartDataSet width

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I have a horizontal chart with multiple **BarChartDataSet** (because they have different colors for **BarChartDataEntry**) But after I added it to **BarChartData** UI looks ugly :(
So the question is how I can configure the width of the **BarChartDataSet**?
I found two properties **barSpace** and **groupSpace** but can't figure out how to use them :)

Here is the code

```
private func updateChartData () {
        //days
        let days = ["", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
        var dataSets:[BarChartDataSet] = []

        let valuesArr = [[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 0.2, 0.7],
                         [3.0, 5.0, 3.6, 2.0, 1.0, 0.2, 0.7],
                         [1.0, 2.0, 6.0, 4.0, 1.5, 0.2, 0.7],
                         [4.0, 3.2, 4.4, 3.0, 2.0, 0.2, 0.7],
                         [0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.1, 2.2, 0.2, 0.7],
                         [0.8, 2.1, 4.3, 3.4, 2.0, 0.2, 0.7],
                         [2.9, 3.3, 4.6, 3.7, 2.8, 0.9, 0.7]]

        for (index, values) in valuesArr.enumerate() {
            let entry = BarChartDataEntry.init(values: values, xIndex: index)
            let set = BarChartDataSet.init(yVals: [entry], label: nil)
//            set.barSpace = 1
            set.drawValuesEnabled = false
            set.colors = [UIColor.clearColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.redColor()]

            dataSets.append(set)
        }

        let data = BarChartData.init(xVals: days, dataSets: dataSets)
//        data.groupSpace = 4
        self.contentView.data = data

        let rightAxis = self.contentView.rightAxis
        rightAxis.enabled = true
        rightAxis.labelFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
        rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
        rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
        rightAxis.axisMinValue = max(0.0, self.contentView.data!.yMin - 1.0)
        rightAxis.axisMaxValue = min(23.0, self.contentView.data!.yMax + 1.0)
        rightAxis.labelCount = Int(rightAxis.axisMaxValue - rightAxis.axisMinValue)
        rightAxis.axisMinValue = 1.0
        rightAxis.axisMaxValue = 23.0

    }
```

and how it looks like after running

[image: Charts with multiple BarChartDataSet]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be achieved by changing the `barSpace` property. Note that's in percentages. If the whole space for a bar is 100%, then a barSpace of 0.25 means that 25% of it will be space, and 75% is for the bar.

Comment: thank you for the reply
I've tried to play with it. I have 7 rows (7 days) that is 100%. So each row is about 14%. If I set 0.14 for barSpace and barSpace looks still not acceptable. But if I set 14 for these values I got [link](http://s32.postimg.org/l4ipjitmt/Simulator_Screen_Shot_May_13_2016_4_24_49_PM.png) but it's not centred :(

Comment: barSpace is relative to the row, not the entire chart. A barSpace of .14 would make it very thick. The centering issue is a different question. You can ask a new one with more code of how you set up your graph, or you can edit above. But I'd need to browse through your setup chart function I believe

Comment: Thank you! I found that iOS charts not support thing that I need

Answer (score 0):

I found that iOS charts is not support spacing between multiple BarChartDataSet :(

> 1 dataSet means one bar, remember that first. Puting more than one y
>   value inside one dataSet will gives you a stacked bar chart. Check
>   them out the ChartsDemo. There are multiple bar charts and stacked bar
>   charts.
>
> For those spacing issues, if ios-charts does not support it yet, then
>   you may need to override the renderer to get what you want, but this
>   will get complicated and requires you understand how the bars is
>   positioned and rendered.

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/365

So I'm going to use one data set. Color for each BarChartDataEntry will be added to array and assigned to BarChartDataSet

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to can change `barWidth` variable inside `HorizontalBarChartRenderer` class in method:

```
public func drawDataSet(context context: CGContext, dataSet: IBarChartDataSet, index: Int)
```

Comment: I see that it used to calculate bottom and top but can't figure out how it can help me. Did you tried it and it works?

Comment: I've edited my answer, look inside HorizontalBarChartRenderer class.
I've played with barWidth = 0.1 and 0.5
here's results:
http://imgur.com/tnXNfQ4
http://imgur.com/RySchfT

Comment: Yeah. But in my case I have multiple data sets. Do you have the same situation? Because with one data set I can change the bar with with property bar space.
When we use multiple data sets something wrong with math of rects for bars (spaces between bars)
Here is what I have with barWidth = 1.0
http://i68.tinypic.com/2mw9wrs.jpg